# Replace multiple words within a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have multiple cells in a spreadsheet which lists two character country ISO codes in a single cell like so:

```
CA, MX, US

CA, MX, US

CA, CR, MX, US

AD, AE, AR, AT, AU, BD, BE, BG, BO, BR, CH, CI, CL

CA, MX, US

GB, US
```

I have another sheet which lists the ISO code and full country name.

I'd like to replace the ISO codes with the full country names.

Does anyone have any suggestion of how I can go about this?

Comment: if you show what you've tried and including any coding or formulas efforts, you much more likely to get a useful response

Comment: Find and replace....

Comment: Not tried any coding as I don't really know where to start. Not that clued up on VBA.

Comment: Find and Replace is what I am using but there are around 250 countries and was hoping someone had a suggestion for something quicker/automated

Comment: It would be pretty cool, if you can use VBA to connect to an online resource and do a find and replace for ISO codes. Something like this http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?op=GetCountryByCountryCode

Comment: Do you have somewhere a list with all the countries and their codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with VBA as follows (you should back up your file in case of rasing any issue)
1. Press Alt + F11 to open VBA 
2. pass the code as follows

```
Sub Multi_FindReplace()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("CA", "MX", "US")
rplcList = Array("canada", "mexico", "usa")

'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next sht

  Next x

End Sub
```

3. Save as xlsm 
4. Run the command (in VBA, press F5)
5. Done
Notes:

```
fndList = Array("CA", "MX", "US")
rplcList = Array("canada", "mexico", "usa")
```

You have to add all the ISO and contries here (using Vlooup and "Concatenate" function for quickly process to generate this string)
For your reference: http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/14/find-and-replace-all